# Is it possible to disclose a method of a private Object?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, reference

Is there a way to shorten the following code:

```
private Map<Foo, Bar> map;

public void addEntry(Foo a, Bar b){
    this.map.put(a,b);
}
```

Into something like this:

```
private Map<Foo, Bar> map;

public void addEntry(Foo a, Bar b) -> this.headers::put;
# OR
public void this.header::put;
```

Basically I want to disclose the put method of a Map instead of making the whole Object public.

Comment: There's no construct to delegate method calls like that in Java.

Comment: Best you would get is probably something like `Lombok`, which is much more limited than what you're suggesting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that code is already as short as it can get and, if the class or method are found to be `final` then it will probably be inlined at runtime, with zero overhead.